# Using django-storages and the s3boto backend, How do I add caching info to request headers for an image so browser will cache image?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I am using the s3boto backend, not the s3 backend.

In the [django-storages docs](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) it says to specify the AWS_HEADERS variable on your 
settings.py file:

> AWS_HEADERS (optional)
>
> If you’d like to set headers sent with each file of the storage:

```
# see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
AWS_HEADERS = {
'Expires': 'Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400',
}
```

This is not working for me.

Here is my model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    """
        docstring for Photo
        represents a single photo.. a photo can have many things associated to it like
        a project, a portfolio, etc...
    """

    def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        return 'user_uploads/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/original/%s' % (instance.owner.username, today.year, today.month, today.day, today.hour, today.minute, filename)

    def thumb_upload_to(instance, filename):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        return 'user_uploads/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/thumb/%s' % (instance.owner.username, today.year, today.month, today.day, today.hour, today.minute, filename)

    def medium_upload_to(instance, filename):
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        return 'user_uploads/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/medium/%s' % (instance.owner.username, today.year, today.month, today.day, today.hour, today.minute, filename)



    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # take out soon
    projects = models.ManyToManyField('Project', through='Connection', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)
    thumb = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=thumb_upload_to, resize_source=dict(size=(102,102), crop='center'),)
    medium = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=medium_upload_to, resize_source=dict(size=(700,525),))
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    caption = models.TextField(blank=True)
    can_view_full_res = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_portfolio = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    disabled = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=False)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mature_content = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = ViewableManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/m/photo/%i/" % self.pk

    def get_prev_by_time(self):
        get_prev = Photo.objects.order_by('-created_time').filter(created_time__lt=self.created_time)
        try:
            return get_prev[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def get_next_by_time(self):
        get_next = Photo.objects.order_by('created_time').filter(created_time__gt=self.created_time)
        try:
            return get_next[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def __unicode__(self):
        return(self.title)
```

This is what is on my template where I have the image...

```
<img class='shadow' src='{{ object.medium.url }}'>
```

Here are the request and response headers:

```
Request URL:https://MY_UPLOAD_CONTAINER.s3.amazonaws.com/user_uploads/travismillward/2012/3/23/3/0/medium/_0677866898.jpg?Signature=s%2ByKsWDxrDJbyeVHd%2BDS3JlByts%3D&Expires=1332529522&AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEYID
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
GET /user_uploads/travismillward/2012/3/23/3/0/medium/_0677866898.jpg?Signature=s%2ByKsWDxrDJbyeVHd%2BDS3JlByts%3D&Expires=1332529522&AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEYID HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_UPLOAD_CONTAINER.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8000/m/photo/1/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
Signature:s+yKsWDxrDJbyeVHd+DS3JlByts=
Expires:1332529522
AWSAccessKeyId:MY_ACCESS_KEYID
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: wOWRRDi5TItAdiYSPf8X4z4I4v5/Zu8XLhwlxmZa8w8w1Jph8WQkenihVJI/ZKnV
x-amz-request-id: THE_X_AMZ_REQUEST_ID
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 18:05:24 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 09:00:13 GMT
ETag: "6e34e718a349e0bf9e4aefc1afad3d7d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 91600
Server: AmazonS3
```

When I paste the path to the image into the address bar it WILL cache the image and give me a 304... Here are those request and response headers:

```
Request URL:https://MY_UPLOAD_CONTAINER.s3.amazonaws.com/user_uploads/travismillward/2012/3/23/3/0/medium/_0677866898.jpg?Signature=evsDZiw3QGsjPacG4CHn6Ji2dDA%3D&Expires=1332528782&AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEYID
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Request Headersview parsed
GET /user_uploads/travismillward/2012/3/23/3/0/medium/_0677866898.jpg?Signature=evsDZiw3QGsjPacG4CHn6Ji2dDA%3D&Expires=1332528782&AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEYID HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_UPLOAD_CONTAINER.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8000/m/photo/1/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
If-None-Match: "6e34e718a349e0bf9e4aefc1afad3d7d"
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 09:00:13 GMT
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
Signature:evsDZiw3QGsjPacG4CHn6Ji2dDA=
Expires:1332528782
AWSAccessKeyId:MY_ACCESS_KEYID
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
x-amz-id-2: LfdHa10SdWnx4UH1rc62NfUDeiNVGRzBX73CR+6GDrXJgv9zo+vyQ9A3HCr1YLVa
x-amz-request-id: THE_X_AMZ_REQUEST_ID
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 18:01:16 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 09:00:13 GMT
ETag: "6e34e718a349e0bf9e4aefc1afad3d7d"
Server: AmazonS3
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you to [blackrobot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28360/blackrobot) who gave me this answer.

Add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Comment: i have same issue, i've set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` and still no help. i see that requests to s3 are made w.o auth part, but nothing shows that `AWS_HEADERS` are working.

Comment: @Neara Will you copy/paste your request headers to a paste bin or something and provide a link? I'll have a look.

Comment: i had an error in `Expires` formatting, and i guess due to that amazon didnt use it. After deploying again after the fix, i now see `Cache-Control` and `Expires` as set in settings. thank you for trying to help me tho, really appreciate it :)